# How to access numba function *args index without a compile time constant

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numba

I have a tuple of numpy.ndarrays (of different dtypes), representing columns from a pandas dataframe.

```py
args = *(seconds[column].values for column in seconds if column!='pair')
```

In order to know the column names I have created a numba typedDict `col_names` looking like this:

```
DictType[unicode_type,int64]<iv=None>({ts: 0, volume: 1, price: 2, ema_14: 3, slope_14: 4})
```

The numba function which takes a dynamic number of numpy.ndarrays into the `*args` tuple, and the col_names typed dictionary.
However, in order to access a specific numpy array I need from the tuple, it won't allow me to do it by calling `args[col_names['ts']`, because `col_names['ts']` is not a compile time constant.

```py
@njit
def numba_function(col_names, *args):
    print(args[col_names['ts']]) # this doesn't work as col_names['ts'] is not compile time constant
    print(args[0]) # this works as 0 is a compile time constant
```

Can you suggest a better approach for this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Numba needs a fixed number of parameters in the target compiled function though it automatically generate a Python wrapper that could support variadic parameters (variadic parameters are possible in low-level native function but with stronger restrictions and this is generally considered unsafe and bug-prone). What about using just a dict of Numpy arrays? Pandas does that internally. The type of the target arrays needs to be homogeneous and known at compile time but this is mandatory for generating a fast code anyway.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your answer! Yes, a numba typed dict of numpy arrays would've worked, but unfortunately, since the dict value needs to be a single type, I won't be able to have values of both np.int64 and np.float64 inside the dictionary.

Comment: You can use 2 dictionaries : one for each type. I used this approach for speeding up dataframes coming from R codes using a native compiled code and it was working well though it is a bit cumbersome. I doubt there is a much better solution for a generic code with a variable number of columns since the datatypes are fundamentally dynamic and Numba fundamentally needs static well defined types at compile time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, will try to implement it and see where how it goes. Will definitely report back after I have some results!

Comment: I'm back with the results, indeed, having multiple dictionaries for each type was a solution, a little bit cumbersome, but it worked. It turns out this way, looping through a dataframe with numba takes around the same amount of time as looping over it with zip(cols), so I will stick to the normal pythonic loop as it way more easier to develop. Thanks again for the replies!

Comment: Just double checked and it seems like the numba looping is about 2X faster, so I'll keep implementing it to see how cumbersome and limiting it gets into my algorithm, fingers crossed it will scale at least a little in the project.